# quirk involving trig substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, improper-integrals

I have reduced the following trig identity to the following which is correct.

$$\int \cos^2(x)\tan^3(x)dx = \int \tan(x) - \sin(x)\cos(x)dx$$

However this next step changes the value of my equation.. i.e False

$$\int \cos^2(x)\tan^3(x)dx = \int \tan(x) dx - \int\sin(x)\cos(x)dx$$

Why can i not do this?

proof below
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28cos^2x*tan^3x%29+%3D+integral%28tanx%29+-+%28sinxcosx%29

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28cos%5E2x%2Atan%5E3x%29+%3D+integral%28tanx%29+-+integral+%28sinxcosx%29

Comment: What? Wolfram gave the exact same result for both.

Comment: oops, both links were pointing to the same page

Comment: I can't follow the first link - but to comment generally, differences in the apparent form of indefinite integrals are quite often down to hidden differences in the constant of integration.

Answer (score 0):

The two integrals that Wolfram gets are not equal (so the equation is false), but the two integrals do differ by a constant, so both are correct indefinite integrals.

Comment: i do not understand your answer completley, i have used similar properties where
$$\int x−x^2 dx = \int x dx − \int x^2 dx$$
why is this property not working in this example? Are you suggesting because one willl have 2 constanst while the other wil only have one?

Comment: There is a ${}+C$ for an indefinite integral.  Mathematica chose its constants differently in the two cases.